# IBM Watson Speech to Text using WebSockets

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am trying to use the Watson Developer Cloud java SDK to transcribe large audio files. I tried the Sessionless method and it works fine, however when I try the WebSockets method things become unreliable.

Most of the time the method will just return with no `SpeechResult` passed to the delegates; rarely it works, but it only transcribes the first couple of seconds.

This is what my code looks like:

```
static SpeechResults transcript = null;
private static String SpeechToText(String audioFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("<!!USERNAME!!>", "<!!PASSWORD!!>");
        service.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");

        RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions();
        options.contentType("audio/ogg;codecs=opus");
        options.continuous(Boolean.TRUE);
        options.inactivityTimeout(-1);
        options.model(Models.GetModelName(Models.SpeechModelEnums.ArabicBroadband));
        options.timestamps(Boolean.TRUE);
        options.wordAlternativesThreshold(0.5);
        options.wordConfidence(Boolean.TRUE);

        options.interimResults(Boolean.FALSE);

        File audio = new File(audioFile);

        //This is my sessionless call
        //SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options);


        service.recognizeUsingWebSockets(new FileInputStream(audio),  options, new BaseRecognizeDelegate()
        {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(SpeechResults speechResults){
                System.out.println(speechResults);                
                }
            }
        );

        return "";//transcript.toString();
    }
```

I have continuous enabled. I tried fiddling with interimResults but that did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? I think they've recently replaced the websockets library. (I myself had the same kind of problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are mentioning was fixed in the `3.0.0-RC1` version.
I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806207/456564) a similar question and added a code snippet that recognizes an audio file using WebSockets.

Starting from the `3.0.0-RC1` there is a WebSocket example in the [README](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk#websocket-support).

Comment: That worked, thanks. However, I noticed in the example you call Thread.sleep() to wait for the asynchronous call. Is there a better way of waiting for the transcribe operation to finish?

Comment: So how do I go about waiting for the transcribe process to finish? Is there an event or a callback that I should handle?

Comment: the `SpeechResults` has a [`isFinal()`](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1/model/SpeechResults.java#L53) method.

Comment: Umm, if I use continuous I get many results with `isFinal()` set to true. I believe `isFinal()` is being set to true whenever a pause is found in the audio but that does not necessarily means that it has reached the end of the file.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was looking at the `Transcript` object's `isFinal()` rather than the one for the `SpeechResult`

Comment: sounds great :-) hey @GermanAttanasio is there any ETA for 3.0.0 stable?

Comment: probably two 2 weeks. RC means that the interface will not change so you don't need to update your code for `3.0.0` but I want to have time to test the WebSocket library enough. I didn't do that with the previous versions and we ended up with lots of questions here.